# XCode - Changes to static libraries doesn't cause the build system to relink the executable

Tags: xcode, build-process, static-libraries, dependency-management

I have a project "blackjack" containing a project (as a child) called "GameLib", which in turn contains many projects such as "Core-iOS". I have libCore-iOS.a added to "Link Binary With Libraries," but changing a .cpp/.mm file in the static libraries doesn't cause the executable to be linked against the new .a file. The .a file *is* being compiled with the changes. Why is the build system broken, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I've determined the minimum reproduction for this problem, and submitted a bug report. This happens if the static-library project is a child of a child (or any descendant not a direct child) of the main project. I know no work around, other than to delete the executable, though sometimes deleting everything (including the output of other build schemes) is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure all of your targets' dependencies.

```
blackjack
  libCore-iOS.a << dependency
```

If Xcode's automatic dependency detection fails, then configure `libCore-iOS` target as a dependency *explicitly*. That then solves it.

If you have found automatic dependency detection in error, please consider submitting a bug report with projects attached. I have found errors in it, but was unable (erm.. *unwilling*) to submit projects for them to debug the issue.

---

To define an Explicit Dependency:

- Open the "blackjack" Project in Xcode
- Select the "blackjack" Project in the Project Navigator (Top-Level)
- Select the "blackjack" Target
- Choose "Build Phases" tab
- Click '+' in "Target Dependencies" phase, and add libGameLib target as a dependency
- Click '+' in "Link Binary With Libraries" phase, and add libGameLib
- Now disable "Find Implicit Dependencies" in all schemes
- Restart Xcode
- Clean and Build Project

That should be all that's needed to create an explicit dependency, unless you have made some atypical mods to your build settings.

Comment: How do I do that? The project structure looks like
blackjack/gamelib/Core-iOS

Comment: @Brent disable the scheme's "Find implicit dependencies", then configure it manually, similar to how one would have done it in Xc3 using the target's Build Phases. You should search for a walk through on this process -- the screenshots are useful.

Comment: While I couldn't find a walkthrough, I did figure out edit scheme... > Build > Targets. Either with or without "Find Implicit Dependencies" it still doesn't work. Worth noting that the dependencies are figured out, because cleaning everything does cause the dependencies to build. But updating just doesn't cause a relink. At any rate, I've submitted a bug report and sample project that's a simple Project A/Project B/ Project C hierarchy, and it has the same problem. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @Brent you need to define the dependency *explicitly* for it to work (assuming the problem is the same). i will search for a step-by-step.

Comment: @Brent ok. nothing i found matched. see step by step above

Comment: Thanks. I followed your steps (which I had tried a few times before). Unfortunately, this is what I see at step 5: http://i.imgur.com/mFHna.jpg Might as well mention, Apple has closed my bug report as a duplicate. Hopefully it'll get addressed soon.

Comment: @Brent ok. the "missing Base SDK" in the GameLib subproject *could* indicate a problem in how the project's configured. that may be causing the dependencies to not appear. i suspect a configuration difference which prevents them from being listed. fwiw, it has never been impossible within my projects to configure dependencies explicitly and ultimately get the build to work (they contain more dependencies than seen in your screenshot). also, thanks a lot for submitting the bug report. note: i wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a fix soon, but it will reduce headaches once fixed.

Comment: @Brent also, if you used Xc3, then you may want to also try approaching it using Xc3. the Xcode 3 approach is what has worked for me (going back to specifying the dependencies explicitly). so trying it in Xc3 could eliminate some sources of problems. it's also likely to be documented better and have more online visibility, since dependencies weren't automatic then.

Comment: Would have shared the link to bug report many comments ago, since it clearly demonstrates an XCode bug. Apple sucks, so I'll just briefly repeat it here. You can literally make 3 empty projects, A, B, and C, where B is inside A, C is inside B, and A depends on C. and you will get this problem. Here's the zipped project: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/76772406/A.zip Build and run, and you will see "Version 1" in the console. In the C project, change the text to "Version 2." Run the project again, still shows "Version 1." My report was even a dupe. For now, just delete intermediate files as needed.

Comment: @Brent apart from the obvious workaround of manually defining each dependency (add C.xcodeproj to A.xcodeproj and go), the approach i often take is to create an intermediate static library in B.xcodeproj (with a dummy file which must not be empty, and one or more linked static libraries). this way, you can avoid managing sub-dependencies for each high level target (e.g. A.xcodeproj). i don't recommend linking all dependencies at all stages -- structure it like a tree. so that intermediate target in B.xcodeproj defines the dependencies and links the sub-modules.